# Remove divider under the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, divider

I want to remove the divider under the ActionBar, already search here for it and tried the different things, but nothing worked for me.

Here are the styles, I hope you can help me.

```
<style name="ListeningThemeTranslucentActionBar" parent="@style/ListeningTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ListeningTranslucentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="ListeningTranslucentActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't apply your styles in the Manifest. You will have to add

```
android:theme="@style/ListeningThemeTranslucentActionBar"
```

in your `Manifest.xml`. (If there is already a `android:theme` parameter just change it to your theme.)

Also [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) link might be helpfull.